# какой тип данных как правило выбирают для поля age ? string или int? int в несколько раз больше памяти занимает но тут же все таки целые числа

Tags: php, laravel

age же как правило максимум 100

Comment: `int`. Не вижу ни одной логической причины где `age` понадобился бы вам как строка.

Comment: на основании чего вы решили, что инт занимает в несколько раз больше памяти? с Интом все понятно, тут условно в зависимости от разрядности ОС будет либо 4 либо 8байт. А вот как вы память считали для строки? И какова вообще мотивация может быть хранить заведомо целочисленное значение в строковом виде? Или вам надо не полных лет хранить? Вообще возраст величина изменяемая, в отличие от даты рождения.

Comment: строка, кстати, помимо самого буфера со значениями, где каждый символ может иметь многобайтную кодировку, в отрицательном смещении так же хранит длину, в виде целого.

Comment: Если уж так страшен int, то храни ShortInt  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Byte достаточно